# Best Windows tool for managing .bib files to be later processed by biblatex?

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, tools

I think this topic is not specifically covered by any of the existing questions about `biblatex`. Sorry if I am wrong.

I am planning to use `biblatex` to include and manage references in my LaTeX document. I already have the source for my references in a `.bib` file that is produced by Mendeley.

I am quite happy with the results till now, but I would like to ask a generic question (so, there is no *minimal working example*, sorry).

I've read in [`biblatex` help](http://mirrors.fe.up.pt/pub/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) that `biblatex` has its own data model, although it is nearly fully compatible with classical BibTeX data model.

Anyway, I wonder if there is a Windows (or multiplatform) program for managing `.bib` files (or that can generate `.bib` files) that is more appropriate when those `.bib` files are going to be processed by `biblatex` package. If so, which is the best one, in your opinion?

Comment: [Jabref](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JabRef) works beautifully for both, bibtex and biblatex. Written in Java it runs on Windows, Mac and Linux.

Comment: Note in particular that JabRef now has '`biblatex`-mode' available.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Jabref](http://jabref.sourceforge.net/) can do it very easily.  You can change Jabref settings to handle biblatex entries in this manner:

In the Jabref window, press the menu `Options` and then `Preferences`

[image]

The preferences window will appear:

[image]

In the submenu `Advanced`, find the `BibLaTeX` mode (the last item) and check it. Then press `OK`. Now Jabref will handle `.bib` entries suitable for use with `BibLaTeX`.

Comment: Thank you! I used JabRef a long time ago, but I see that it has been improved. And that option that you mention... it's *perfect*.

Answer (score 1):

[cb2bib](http://www.molspaces.com/d_cb2bib-download.php) is small, easy, multiplatform, supports multiple languages, and has search functionality.

If you use a non-latin language, open the .bib file and add (for Arabic, for example):

Encoding : Cp1256

This number is language dependent.

Comment: No need to sign your answer or add greetings. (TeX.SX! is not a discussion forum.) You also might want to fix the grammar. It will increase the likelyhood of your answer being upvoted and accepted.